# what is symbol s in flex regular expression

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I am trying to understand a flex rule from a legacy code, can you help:

```
number  [0-9]*['']s?[bdh]
```

1. What does the '' (two single quotes) mean? Does it mean a single quote, where the first quote symbol is an escape for the actual quote noted later? I had the impression that special characters would need to marked with a backslash, as in [\'] . If '' indicates ', then what is the right way to use backslash as an escape character?
2. what does the "s" symbol mean here?

Can you give some examples where these two pieces of the regular expression will match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex patterns are documented in the [manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns).

- `s` just matches the letter "s"
- A sequence of characters inside brackets, like `[bdh]`, is a character class. It matches a single character which is any one of the characters in the class. Most characters lose their special meaning when used inside a character class.
- `'` has no special meaning in a flex pattern; like `s`, it just matches itself. And repeating a character inside a character class has no effect. So `['']` matches a single apostrophe, and it could have been written simply as `'`. However, many programmer's editors think that apostrophes are used to surround string or character literals, and a single apostrophe causes syntax highlighting to fail. Writing `['']` is one way to avoid this misunderstanding. (Personally, I think it's better to find a good editor rather than to modify your code to compensate for a stupid editor, but tastes differ.)

Answer (score 1):

1. I think the double apostrophe is just a mistake. Brackets define a character set, and apostrophes have no special meanings. The meaning of double apostrophes inside of brackets has just the meaning of a character set containing only one apostrophe, and this is equivalent to just a single apostrophe.
2. The meaning of a alphabetic character is just the character. Thus, `s` just means `s`. The suffixed question mark makes it optional.

Thus, your expression should be equivalent to

```
number  [0-9]*'s?[bdh]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The other answer is similar but more detailed, so I accepted that one.